# Add top.links to the header Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, layout

I create a custome theme based on Blank theme, I want to display top.links in header like in the following image:

[image]

How I can add that links and much important that Basket like in the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=> Go to your custom theme & add this below code :-

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Cart</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link1">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Checkout</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>                   
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>  
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link1">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/login/</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>                   
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I not see where is the Basket total?

Answer (score -1):

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your.global.link.identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: and how I can add basket link with total?

Comment: you should set attribute data-mage-init, create js script and update link from js or set custom template for link and use custom renderers for that also can be usefull both variants

Comment: can you update your answer and put this modifications there too?